# NAT style port forwarding on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, port-forwarding, nat

I would like to know, is it possible to implement NAT style port forwarding on Windows? Native (included with the OS) solution is preferred, but third party tool would be fine too.

Let's say, I want to forward TCP `127.0.0.1:8080` to `127.0.0.1:80`. But port `8080` is already opened by another application that can't be closed, the port is hard-coded in it and can't be changed. The ultimate goal it to connect to the app that listens on `80` while connecting via `127.0.0.1:8080` and to keep that another app opened.

By NAT style port forwarding I imply a method that changes the port number in the network packets like iptables do. Using iptables I can accomplish the task this way: `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80`.

Solutions that listen on the port, like SSH or NETSH (`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=8080 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=80`) will not fit because the port is already in use.

Comment: Hi! I was wondering, is it a strict requirement that the ports are actually rewritten? To understand your situation correctly; an http reverse proxy wouldn't work because there is already a process listening on the port which needs to be translated?

Comment: @jvda, Yes, reverse proxy wouldn't work because the port (8080) is already in use. And that is why I suspect that the only option is to rewrite port number in the packets on the early stage.